# Select tag not printing via window.print() in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, select, drop-down-menu

Im working in a web appliation that uses `Javascript` in Wordpress.

The problem is: when I try to print the webpage via `window.print()`, the select boxes are not printing.

This **doesnt work only in wordpress**. I tried the same code in Codepen and it works (http://codepen.io/flashter/pen/qNwqLz).

Here is the code:

JAVASCRIPT

```
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
```

HTML

```
<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

<select>
            <option value="1">Option1</option>
            <option value="2">Option2</option>
            <option value="3">Option3</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>
```

Here you can see the wordpress page and the pdf I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9xCQ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to that whether any media query has been written for print option. **@media print** . Hence i am using the same code in **Enigma Theme** and the page what you have given seems to print. Check on the media properties alone . There is no Error in the Code that you have posted.

Comment: Sorry but Im newbie, where can I find the media properties? I dont use `CSS`, just `Javascript` via _CSS & Javascript Toolbox_.

Comment: What theme are you using can you let me know.

Comment: _Twenty Sixteen_. I found the CSS and there is `select` in `@media print`.

Comment: `@media print {
 form,
 button,
 input,
 select,
 textarea,
 .navigation,
 .main-navigation,
 .social-navigation,
 .sidebar,
 .content-bottom-widgets,
 .header-image,
 .page-links,
 .edit-link,
 .comment-respond,
 .comment-edit-link,
 .comment-reply-link,
 .comment-metadata .edit-link,
 .pingback .edit-link {
  display: none;
 }` Remove the display none from here.

Comment: or it is better you just remove up the select from @media print.

Comment: Fine. Thanks. Rock on.